# How do I set up a domain name to redirect to another URL and then check referrers from that domain?

Tags: redirect, google-analytics, seo, cpanel

I'm running a print campaign and have bought a specific URL to try and measure the efficacy of that advert.

I'm using cPanel and Google Analytics.

I want people to type in the new, advert specific URL and be redirected to my actual, live domain name and I would like it to show up in Google analytics as a referrer so I can track how many people visit that website address.

I haven't a single idea how to do this properly. i've set it up as an addon domain in cPanel, and have also set it to redirect to my main URL from within cPanel, but at first glance in "real time" and "traffic sources" it just says "direct", but I want it to show this URL.

So to sum up, I want people to type in a URL, it then redirect and for it to show up in analytics as a referrer, by name. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here you can find a little escamotage: [Tracking 301 Redirects with Google Analytics](http://www.lanevance.com/web/web-development/tracking-301-redirects-with-google-analytics/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it, and here's how I did it:

I set the domain name up as an addon domain on my cpanel account.

Then I created a .htaccess in the root of that subdomain, with the following content:

`# Permanent URL redirect
Redirect 301 / http://www.DomainName.co/?utm_source=Domain-Name.co.uk&utm_medium=mediumName&utm_content`